# Jupyter notebook can not import module installed in the same environment

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment using conda and then I have installed tensorflow within this environment. I can import it when I run interactive python shell. However, I can not import the tensorflow module within jupyter notebook.

Comment: Where is jupyter notebook installed?

Comment: it is installed in the global environment

Answer (score 1):

You need install Jupyter into same environment. Activate the environment with tensorflow and:

```
conda install jupyter
```

to make sure you use the corresponding jupyter start with:

```
python -m jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two installations of python on your box. When you run your notebook, run the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and then

```
import os
print(os.environ['PATH'])
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

Make sure they are pointing the location where you installed tensorflow. You can check where you installed tensorflow by running from the command line:

```
pip show -f tensorflow
```

or from the shell by running:

```
import tensorflow 
tensorflow.__file__
```

Answer (score 0):

As David said, you probably have two installation of python on you machine,
check `sys.path` from your environment in terminal and from your notebook, they should ideally point to your local environment.
To use jupyter notebook from your local environment install it and run kernel using
`python -m jupyter notebook`